# Cors SET-COOKIE header

Tags: authentication, cross-domain, setcookie, samesite

**Answered by Daniel W.**

```
My mistake was that I was calling a HTTP server endpoint instead of it's HTTPS version.
```

Other questions hit the same subject but the issue is not solved after all attempts.

**My issue:**

I can't log in from my second JS client:

- https://localhost:4433 works fine (SET-COOKIE header exists and the cookie is set)
- https://localhost is not working (SET-COOKIE header exists but a cookie is not set)

**Login endpoint:**

http://localhost:8000/home/login

**Response header:**

```
    Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Cookies=SomeCookieHere; expires=Sun, 10 Sep 2022 14:12:52 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    $.post({
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/home/login', 
        data: {"userName":"userName","password":"password"},
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType: "text/html",
        success: function(data) {}
    });
```

**C#:**

```
    authBuilder.AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/");
    })
```

Comment: In the JS you have `http://localhost:8000/`. Please explain the difference between the 3 targets in your question. From which site are you doing the ajax request, from which site do you send the cookie?

Comment: Daniel, 

- Server: http://localhost:8000/home/login

- Client 1: https://localhost:4433 is a ASP-Vue client, working fine

- Client 2: https://localhost - a simple JS client, not working

Comment: If you shutdown the server on port 4433 and restart it on port 443 it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a secure cookie in a non-secure context:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

> A cookie with the Secure attribute is sent to the server only with an encrypted request over the HTTPS protocol, never with unsecured HTTP, and therefore can't easily be accessed by a man-in-the-middle attacker. Insecure sites (with http: in the URL) can't set cookies with the Secure attribute.

```
$.post({
    // url: 'http://localhost:8000/home/login', // Can't use HTTP endpoint
    url: 'https://localhost:4433/home/login', // This works
});
```

Comment: there was no warnings related to my attempt to authenticate an HTTPS client against a HTTP server endpoint.
But this solved my issue. Using the HTTPS version of the endpoint worked. 
I lost so much time on this.

Comment: @profimedica I don't know ASP but you can remove this `options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;` while developing, or install a certificate locally and use https.

Comment: I have both the development certificate and the secure policy set to none as the cookie shows: secure; samesite=none; httponly

Comment: @profimedica the attribute `secure` in the cookie is originating from `options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;`